# Почему «закомплексованный» пишется с одной «н» в кратких формах?

Tags: орфография, нн, краткое-прилагательное, н

*Закомплексованный* [мальчик] — это типичное прилагательное (имеющий комплексы, стеснительный).
Согласно правилам русского языка, в кратком прилагательном пишется столько "н", сколько и в полной форме. С какой стати тогда академики за норму считают "н" в кратких формах этого слова (*-ана, -ано, -аны*)?

---

*Дополняю ответом из института русского языка

---

Добрый день, глубокоуважаемый господин Салис!

В ответ на Ваш запрос от 24.01.2023 г. можем сообщить следующее.

Слово закомплексованный, как Вы совершенно справедливо отметили, является именем прилагательным, которое по форме соотносится со страдательными причастиями прошедшего времени. В краткой форме такие прилагательные могут писаться как с двумя нн (образованна, возвышенна и др.), так и с одной н (парализована, засалена и др.).

В полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина 2006 г. (электронная версия издания доступна в сети Интернет на странице с адресом: [https://orfogrammka.ru/библиотека/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0/)) указывается, что краткие формы (кроме формы мужского рода) прилагательных с качественным значением, совпадающих по форме со страдательными причастиями прошедшего времени глаголов совершенного вида, пишутся с нн (ср.: она избалованна, она дисциплинированна), однако некоторые прилагательные на -нный в краткой форме пишутся с одной н, если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени [см. раздел «Орфография», § 101, 102]. Основанием для кодификации прилагательного закомплексованный в краткой форме с одной н послужил тот факт, что в литературной речи это прилагательное не образует формы сравнительной степени: так, в основном подкорпусе Национального корпуса русского языка (ссылка на страницу: https://ruscorpora.ru/) не содержится примеров употребления словоформы закомплексованнее / закомплексованней.

Таким образом, слово закомплексованный, употребленное, к примеру, в словосочетании закомплексованный ребенок, безусловно, следует квалифицировать как имя прилагательное (не причастие), которое, однако, в краткой форме пишется с одной н, в соответствии с общим орфографическим правилом и рекомендацией, содержащейся на сайте орфографического академического ресурса «Академос» (ссылка на страницу: https://orfo.ruslang.ru/).
С наилучшими пожеланиями
Евгений Базаров, сотрудник отдела культуры русской речи ИРЯ РАН

Comment: https://ask.fm/russian/answers/171642476860

Comment: Я задал вопрос "Грамоте.ру" вчера, специалист сказала, что согласна со мной: она тоже видит в этом слове безусловное значение прилагательного. Она предложила задать вопрос в ИРЯ. Спустя месяц получу ответ от них.

Comment: Я тоже задавал вопрос Грамоте.ру, но ответ не получил. А вам как ответили— личным сообщением или на сайте? На сайте вопроса я не видел сегодня.

Comment: А почему спустя месяц? Телефонная служба не работает?

Comment: На сайте мне никогда не отвечают. Звонил. Сказали, что лучше сделать это письменно.

Comment: А можно звонить в Грамоту.ру.

Comment: ))Грамота не дала ответ на вопрос, она сказала написать обращение в ИРЯ.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Как она вам сказала — письменно или устно? Если устно, значит вы звонили ей?

Comment: Да. Звонил. Устно, конечно.

Comment: А-а, просто я не знал, что можно звонить в Грамоту ру. Поэтому удивился.

Comment: Конечно можно. На сайте они не отвечают никогда.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142343/discussion-between--and-ajgy).

Comment: Когда они ответят, ответьте их сообщением на этот вопрос. Здесь можно отвечать на свои вопросы.

Comment: Ок. Напишу обязательно.

Comment: Вспомнил, что у Розенталя было о приставках. У него есть ответ на этот вопрос, в примечаниях: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62

Comment: Там примеры, так сказать, другого толка.

Comment: Ну всё-равно приставка формирует глагольность, будто её закомплексовали.

Comment: Это неверный метод. так можно сказать и про прилагательное, возникшее из причастия: воспитанна - ее воспитали/избалованная - ее избаловали. Но это ложный путь, ведь в данных словах мы имеем в виду постоянный признак: вежливый/капризный. Как здесь - стеснительный.

Comment: Спорно, но приставка в любом случае формирует глагольность. И у Розенталя сказано: "с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола". А вот достаточно ли этой глагольности — вот что спорно. Пример: *дрессированная собака; выдрессированная собака* (больше глагольности).

Comment: Приставка есть и у причастий, создающих эти прилагательные. В других же случаях мы отличаем эти части речи, а здесь нет - нелогично. Да и ваше "ее закомплексовали" звучит совсем не по-русски.

Comment: Да, звучит, поэтому там "будто". У нас есть факт: приставка увеличивает глагольность. А вот дальнейшие действия... Дальше спорно. То есть здесь есть "за" и "против".

Comment: Ну ещё есть одно "против": слово длинное, удлинять согласную не очень удобно. Да, длина тоже влияет. Но "за" здесь больше, чем одно "против".

Comment: Оледд. Ответьте на мой вопрос сегодняшний.

Comment: Как раз пишу там комментарий. Но похоже на недочёт Розенталя. Кажется, что причина в том, что нельзя переставить. Но оказывается, что истинная причина в примыкании "а" к придаточному. То есть пояснение Розенталя не первостепенно. Ему надо было объяснить свои примеры, а в них нельзя переставить, тоже причина. Очень сложно написать в общем, чтобы никакому примеру не противоречило. К сожалению, ему такой экзотический пример не попался. В основном он выводил правила исходя из примеров, а не подбирал примеры под правила.

Comment: Cпасибо за апдейт, @Ajgy! Любопытно. У Лопатина формулировка для одного Н "если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени", причем из контекста следует, что должны быть оба признака. Зависимых слов у "закомплексована" не требуется, а степень сравнения есть, это находится в гугле. Разговорная речь - часть литературной.

Comment: Меня тоже смутил момент с отсутствием степени сравнения . То, что ее не зафиксировано в НКРЯ, не говорит о том, что ее  не может быть в принципе: я закомплексованнее тебя. Звучит вполне логично.

Comment: Штош. Чему нас учит сей случай? Верьте словарю. Там бывают опечатки, но ошибки очень маловероятны, там много этапов согласования и решает не один человек, а группа. А вот объяснения, почему так, могут быть не совсем очевидными - потому что их составляет конкретный человек. Это, кстати, касается и Грамоты, там немало противоречивых ответов. (Если что - мне почему-то не приходят ваши уведомления, могу не сразу ответить.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, словари фиксируют написание с одной ***н*** в кратких формах:

[**закомплексованный;**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x&help=1) *кр. ф.* -ан, -ана

У Розенталя в пункте **7** параграфа "[Буквы ***нн*** и ***н*** причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62)" есть такая информация:

> **Примечание.** Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя ***н (нн)***, а в краткой — с одним ***н***, подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает **наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола**: *заплака**нн**ые глаза — глаза заплака**н**ы; заржавле**нн**ые ножи — ножи заржавле**н**ы; поноше**нн**ое платье — платье поноше**н**о.*

Не всегда можно определиться с написанием, так что смотрим на всякий случай словари.
А академики тоже люди: что-то недописали, где-то не учли и пр.

Вот в таком примере, мне кажется, и не напишешь с ***нн***:
*Но она молчит, потому что закомплексова**н**а.*
А здесь можно: *Она не может ответить, потому что очень взволнова**нн**а.*

**Вывод:** Каждое слово индивидуально, его нужно рассматривать в контексте, в окружении других слов. Тем более что в языке – исключение на исключении и исключением погоняет.
Зато как интересно в мире Языка!

Comment: Но всё-равно спорно, в этих примерах есть действие. Мой комментарий прочитали? Через минуту ответ появился.

Comment: @oleedd За минуту ответ не получился бы :) Вот именно, что решают "академисты", а нам остается гадать и сверяться, думать о глагольности или качестве... Может, помните мой вопрос о "расслабленны или расслаблены"? То же самое.

Comment: За минуту с чем-то (менее двух). Уложиться можно :) Да, помню, там пришлось напрягаться. Тоже приставка.

Comment: Похоже, что в примере "не" пропустили.

Comment: @oleedd Та не, пусть так останется: комплексы разные бывают, и бурная реакция может служить защитой от непринятых или бессознательных моментов.

Comment: Закомплексованные не реагируют бурно, они теряются.

Comment: @oleedd Это самое распространенное (бытовое) значение слова. Но хорошо, исправлю.

Comment: Всё равно не то :) Как-то же должна реагировать. Надо: *Она бурно не реагирует на такое...* Всего лишь "не" добавить, и нормальный пример.

Comment: @oleedd Ну вот никак она не реагирует, внешних проявлений нет, делает вид, что ничего не происходит. Ой, не о том мы говорим. Но поддамся, исправляю :)

Comment: Покраснеет, глаза опустит, посмотрит как-то в ответ (чаще всего это), взволнуется (мимика), отвернётся... Тем более что обычный человек реагировал бы бурно.

Comment: А почему "и не напишешь"? Это ж самое интересное. Там как раз то, о чём говорит Ajgy.

Comment: @oleedd Я написал: "мне кажется". Ну вот так я чувствую это слово, оно сближено с причастием.

Comment: А я вот не чувствую так, но удобнее произносить без удвоения (длина влияет).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Саша, спасибо за исправление моего ляпсуса в шапке (я чуть не задохнулась от собственной оплошности). Виновата! Приношу извинения всем-всем. Не оправдываюсь, но прошу понять — еще не совсем здорова...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Быстрейшего выздоровления!